# selecting all field_data_body for all content types

Tags: nodes

We are trying to search all text_long or text_with_summary fields for all content type nodes.  I can do it for the field_data_body.  I need to expand this for all content types using text_long and text_with_summary.  I would like to iterate all nodes for all content types and select all fields in the node with the text_long and text_with_summary field type.

Here is what I use for selecting just the body.  I use a cursor to search each db which is why I have a v_db variable.  Don't worry about v_db and @j is the search string I pass to the select statement.  I wish there was a nice GUI for visualizing joins.

select "',v_db,'", ',v_db,'.node.nid, LEFT(',v_db,'.node.title,30), LEFT(',v_db,'.body.body_value,300) from ',v_db,'.node INNER JOIN ',v_db,'.field_data_body AS body ON node.nid = body.entity_id WHERE body.body_value like ',@j);

thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with Views? You know about Views, correct?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something a bit similar a while ago, and used the drupal field definition tables to identify the field type (text/long et al) and work from there to the nodes. I suggest you do likewise.

You could consider using the mysql fulltext search facilities - it is much faster and much more capable than 'like'.

Of course, the drupal way would be to configure the search module properly...